# Limit text field length

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

Please tell me how I can set the range of a text field to a maximum of six and minimum of one.

Comment: It would be nice of you to accept a correct answer to your question by clicking the gray checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

Set self as textfield's delegate and implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if (newString.length < 1) {
        // too short
    } else if (newString.length > 6) {
        // too long
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I'd suggest you to have a UILabel that will say in red text that text is too short or too long. Just preventing user from typing into textfield when they reach 6 chars or deleting last character when they change their mind is a very bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the delegate method `textField:shouldReplaceCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and have your implementation return `NO` if the resulting string would fall outside of your constraints.